How to have non-minified files to be rendered on DEBUG configuration
I have C# asp.net framework Visual Studio solution. The .aspx/.ascx files do have a script tag written. Since we use a minified mechanism outside of Visual Studio, minified files are being referenced on the pages.
e.g.
The problem is that whenever I want to debug, I need to remove the .min from the script tag so that the non-minified file is rendered.
The problem is, that developers often forget to put the .min back to the .aspx/.ascx files, and then the non-minified files get rendered in non-prod and prod environments.
I am looking for a solution, where I can remove the .min.js from the script file, whenever the web project runs in the DEBUG configuration, so that
-developers do not have to make this change and later forget to put the .min back into the code base.
So, in theory, this is what I am trying to achieve
In the DEBUG configuration, I should have the script tag to be <script src=abc.js></script>
I think it can be done with some sort of code behind the code to insert the entire script tag.
I do not think I can go with RegisterStartUpScript part, as I have files in MVC as well.
tried if I can perform a code-behind C# code to insert a script tag, could not succeed.

For .NET Framework: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification - particularly see the section about debugging.

For .NET Core and later: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/bundling-and-minification?view=aspnetcore-8.0

The idea is to have both the min and non min, and when you set the project to  not debug, and publish it, then the minimized version(s) of the js files are used. In fact, when we had a broken minimizer, we for some time published using debug mode, and ran with non minimized files.  The basic issue here is that you not including both js files, and letting .net at publish time pick the correct js files for you.  Since you adopted a minimizing solution outside of VS, then I can only suggest that you develop with the js files, and then your after build scripts will create the min versions.

Keep in mind that even on the production server, if you set debug=false, then the regular "non" min versions of the js files are used. So, really, the only practical solution I can think of is to always have both the min and non min files included in your project.

If you're just trying to vary the name of the script based on if a debugger is attached or not you can try this approach:
<script src="<%=(System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached ? "abc.js" : "abc.min.js")%>"></script>

